# Samba permissions issue

Tags: permissions, samba

I am configuring samba shares.
I want folder1 has 777 and subfolders 755 but its not working

```
[folder1]
    comment= share folder
    path = /srv/samba/folder1
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    writable = yes
    create mask = 777
    create directory mask = 777
    force create mode = 777
    force directory mode = 777


[folder2]
    path = /srv/samba/folder1/folder2
    browsable = no
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    writable = yes
    create mask = 755
    force create mask = 755
    directory mask = 755
    force directory mask = 755
```

When I create a new folder on folder2 it gets 777 permissions

I tried to coment on folder1; 
        force create mode = 777
        force directory mode = 777

but not working

Thanks

Comment: *How* are you trying to create a folder in `folder2`?  If you connect to \\server\folder1 then cd to folder2 then the permissions on the share `folder1` apply; if you connect to \\server\folder2 then the permissions on the share `folder2` will apply.

Comment: Hi Alex,If I connect to  \\server\folder2 the result is the same. The folders are 777 permissions.